# What is the Fourier Transform of $\DeclareMathOperator{\rect}{rect} \rect(2Bt)\cos[{\omega}_Ct + k_fm(t_k)t] $?

Tags: fourier-transform, frequency-modulation

What is the Fourier Transform of $\rect(2Bt)\cos[{\omega}_Ct + k_fm(t_k)t] $?

I got the following as the solution:

$$\DeclareMathOperator{\sinc}{sinc} \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{2B} \sinc(\frac{\omega+{\omega}_C+k_fm(t_k) +}{4B}) + \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{2B} \sinc(\frac{\omega-{\omega}_C-k_fm(t_k) +}{4B})$$

However, in the book it is given as:

$$ \frac{1}{2} \sinc(\frac{\omega+{\omega}_C+k_fm(t_k) +}{4B}) + \frac{1}{2}  \sinc(\frac{\omega-{\omega}_C-k_fm(t_k) +}{4B})$$

Wolfram alpha shows this:

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Fourier+transform+calculator&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22FourierTransformCalculator%22%2C+%22transformfunction%22%7D+-%3E%22+rect%282Bt%29cos%28pt%29%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22FourierTransformCalculator%22%2C+%22variable1%22%7D+-%3E%22t%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22FourierTransformCalculator%22%2C+%22variable2%22%7D+-%3E%22w%22

Comment: you should have $2B$ outside of the $\sinc$, so I'm pretty sure your book can't be right, unless $B$ is defined somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define the $\textrm{rect}()$ function according to [this definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectangular_function), then your result is correct.
However, there might be a problem with the definition of the $\textrm{rect}()$ function. If in your book they define that function to have unit area, then the result of the book would be correct.

Comment: I have used this text of B.P Lathi :https://www.academia.edu/36135973/Book_Modern_Digital_And_Analog_Communication_Systems_4th_edition_by_Lathi

Comment: Can it be possible that the book has defined the rect function to have unit area? Please refer to page no. 212. Thank you.

Comment: @AnwesaRoy: I actually don't think so, but just check if the author defines rect() somewhere in the book. But it's actually not a problem, just make sure that you understand the correctness of the result, whatever the result in the book may be. Even the best books have some errors.

Comment: They have defined the rect(t) function just the way you have defined. Thanks for helping me out :)